# using xstream to serialize a class without its extended class

Tags: java, serialization, xstream, extends

I have two classes:

```
class ObjectCollection {
    Object[] collection;
}
```

and

```
class Object extends AnotherObject {

}
```

Now, on serializing these with XStream, it gets everything right, but it also adds data from AnotherObject to each Object. Is there a way to tell XStream to ignore elements from the extended class not wanted?

Answer (score 0):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795138/make-xstream-ignore-one-specific-private-variable). However, if the objects should be the same, why have 2 classes?